# nth child css selecting

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to figure out how to use `nth` to select the one out of every 3 elements in a group of objects.

If my markup is structured like this:

```
<div class="all-items">
  <div class="block">
    <a href="the-link">
      <div class="image-list">
        <div class="drop-shadow curved curved-hz-1">
          <img src="an-image.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- then this repeats to show all the images -->
  <div class="block">
    <a href="the-link">
      <div class="image-list">
        <div class="drop-shadow curved curved-hz-1">
          <img src="an-image.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- ... etc. -->

</div> <!-- end div class "all-items" -->
```

How can I select every 3rd `img` in the group of images inside `<div class="all-items">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select every third `.block`'s image:

```
.block:nth-child(3n) img {
    /* styles */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sC8Ne/

Comment: Thanks @Wesley. This is what I was looking for. I will accept when the timer is finished. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a couple references for the future: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/understandingnthchildexpressions, http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 3):

```
div.block:nth-child(3n) img { /*your css here*/ }
```

You're selecting the 3 block of divs, then the image inside that.

Comment: Thanks! This only selects the first element in the group, however. @Wesley correctly pointed out that I need to select using `3n`. I will award the answer to him since he provided the correct answer first, but I really appreciate your input! (+1)

Comment: Sorry I missed out the 'n'